# Do JVMs create significant overhead in distributed/ parallel processing?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, jvm

If a distributed computing framework spins up nodes for running   Java/ Scala operations then it has to include the JVM in every container. E.g. every Map and Reduce step spawns its own JVM.

How does the efficiency of this instantiation compare to spinning up containers for languages like Python? Is it a question of milliseconds, few seconds, 30 seconds? Does this cost add up in frameworks like Kubernetes where you need to spin up many containers?

I've heard that, much like Alpine Linux is just a few MB, there are stripped down JVMs, but still, there must be a cost. Yet, Scala is the first class citizen in Spark and MR is written in Java.

Comment: I believe that without exact definition of what "significant overhead" is, this question will be closed as primary opinion based. Also don't forget that performance of the program is not the only important metric for choosing the tool. Otherwise everybody would still probably write code in Assembly and at most C.

Comment: you can test this for yourself. pull both the openjdk and python:3 images and time 
`docker run python:3 python3 --version` and  `docker run openjdk java --version`.  tldr: it's not as significant as you might think.

Comment: My personal experience is that any function you either define as a UDF or map to a partition is going to be MUCH more costly in Python than in Java/Scala. In fact, I'm lead on a team that translated our entire code base from pyspark to Scala for this very reason; memory usage was blowing up our clusters with pyspark. Don't worry about the cost of the JVM itself, instead worry about the cost of what is being serialized across the cluster by pyspark. I assert that Scala or Java would be much more memory efficient than Python.

Answer (score 1):

Linux container technology uses layered filesystems so bigger container images don't generally have a ton of runtime overhead, though you do have to download the image the first time it is used on a node which can potentially add up on truly massive clusters. In general this is not usually a thing to worry about, aside from the well known issues of most JVMs being a bit slow to start up. Spark, however, does not spin up a new container for every operation as you describe. It creates a set of executor containers (pods) which are used for the whole Spark execution run.